# Autofill via VBA results in column clearing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty familiar with VBA so this is a very strange problem. I'm attempting to autofill separate column ranges after importing data. Everything works fine and columns A:C autofill correctly but the autofill for column AT results in the entire column clearing. I've made sure the correct formula is in cell AT2. I may just have a stupid mistake in the code but I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim wbCopy As Workbook
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet
Dim FileCopy As String
Dim rgCopy As Range, rgPaste As Range
Dim lRowPaste As Long

FileCopy = "C:\Users\Nick\File.csv"
Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(FileCopy)
Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Sheets(1)

Set wsPaste = Workbooks("Stats").Sheets("Logs")

Set rgCopy = wsCopy.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rgCopy = rgCopy.Resize(rgCopy.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)

Set rgPaste = wsPaste.Range("D2")
Set rgPaste = rgPaste.Resize(rgCopy.Rows.Count, rgCopy.Columns.Count)

rgPaste.Value2 = rgCopy.Value2

wbCopy.Close savechanges:=False

lRowPaste = wsPaste.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wsPaste.Range("A2:C" & lRowPaste).FillDown '-----> DOES WORK

wsPaste.Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=wsPaste.Range("AT2:AT" & lRowPaste) '-----> DOES NOT WORK
wsPaste.Range("AT2:AT" & lRowPaste).FillDown '-----> DOES NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont see any problem but you can try replace this part:

```
With wsPaste

lRowPaste = .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Range("A2:C" & lRowPaste).FillDown '-----> DOES WORK

.Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AT2:AT" & lRowPaste) '-----> DOES NOT WORK
.Range("AT2:AT" & lRowPaste).FillDown '-----> DOES NOT WORK

End With
```

with this:

```
With wsPaste

lRowPaste = .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Range("A2:C" & lRowPaste).FillDown '-----> DOES WORK

.Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AT2:AT" & lRowPaste) '-----> DOES NOT WORK
.Range("AT2:AT" & lRowPaste).FillDown '-----> DOES NOT WORK

End With
```

and check if lastrow get the correct value in order to confirm that you use the right range.

Comment: I gave that a shot, same result. I'm really stumped...fortunately its a minor issue but it really makes no sense.